# Adding options to node elements

Tags: angular, tiptap

I am building an Angular 11 app.
In this app I am using the Tiptap editor.

I am creating a custom node to support div elements.

**The code for this custom node is:**

```
import { Node, mergeAttributes } from '@tiptap/core';

const Div = Node.create({
  name: 'div',
  defaultOptions: {
    HTMLAttributes: {},
  },
  content: 'block*',
  group: 'block',
  defining: true,
  parseHTML() {
    return [
      { tag: 'div' },
    ];
  },
  renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    return ['div', mergeAttributes(this.options.HTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes), 0];
  },
});

export default Div;
export { Div };
```

**How can I set a class to the div, I tried this.**

```
public content: any = {
    type: 'doc',
    content: [
      {
        type: 'div',
        attrs: {
          class: 'custom-class',
        },
        content: [
          {
            type: 'paragraph',
            content: [
              {
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Example ',
              },
              {
                type: 'text',
                marks: [
                  {
                    type: 'bold',
                  },
                ],
                text: 'Text',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class in `HTMLAttributes`:

```js
import { Node, mergeAttributes } from '@tiptap/core';

const Div = Node.create({
  name: 'div',
  defaultOptions: {
    HTMLAttributes: {
      // you can set custom class here
      class: 'custom-class',
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes, but I need it to be dynamic, for example <div class="block-item-header">. How can I set it dynamically? If I use <div class="block-item-header"> it ignores the class and removes it from the output.

Comment: @MarkDenn can you give a simple example on stackblitz?